# Is there a way to identify all wire locations in LabVIEW?

Tags: labview

I was curious on how much distance of wires I had in an VI... so naturally I'm attempting to measure all of the wires given a specific vi. I'm aware of the inherent issues such as zoom, pixel density and its correlation to distance, etc. I just can't seem to find much info on identifying wires from a VI, much less getting their location on a screen. Any and all feedback is appreciated, this is just a fun little project I thought I'd challenge myself with.

I attempted to use a Traverse GObjects function to identify wires... That probably shows how new I am to everything. I couldn't manage to get the identities of the wires this way.

Answer (score 1):

The term you want to search is "VI Scripting". You were on the right track with Traverse GObjects. If you give that the name input "Wire", it will give you back a reference to all the wires on the diagram. The type will be GObject, so you'll need to use To More Specific node to downcast the references to the Wire class. After that, you can query the properties of the wire objects to get the information you seek.

Answer (score 1):

Quite funny, but seems to be easy task.

This is the VI snippet, just drag-and-drop it onto your block diagram

[image: VI snippet]

Comment: Haha I thought so as well, but couldn't quite manage it myself. Thanks a ton! I'll be sure to dissect that vi, much appreciated!